# Abstraction = encapsulation + data hiding?

Tags: oop, encapsulation, abstraction

I have gone through lots of posts but did not get the point.

Can we say : abstraction = encapsulation + data hiding

Or it is more than that!!

Thanks

Comment: One has nothing to do with the other.  Your question is off-topic too

Comment: Have you read [What does abstraction mean in programming?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21220155/3744182) and [Simple way to understand Encapsulation and Abstraction](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16014290) and [Encapsulation vs Abstraction?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960918) ?  Do those address your question?

Comment: The following reading will clear all your doubts: [Abstraction, Encapsulation, and Information Hiding](http://www.tonymarston.co.uk/php-mysql/abstraction.txt)

Answer (score 2):

This question is more of an object oriented question. #oop would be a good tag to include here.

To answer your question: 
No, abstraction does not equal encapsulation and data hiding. By the way abstraction and encapsulation both have data hiding concepts. However, they are not the same.

**Encapsulation** is about hiding variables or methods within a class to prevent any changes from the outside world. **Then we can control what is being manipulated through getter/setter methods**. Brief example is when we have a Person class. In this Person class let's assume we have a variable to keep track of age. Now, we have a GetAge() method to return the age of the Person; on the other hand, we have modified the SetAge(int age) method to only set the new age if the passed in argument is a greater age than the current age (because we only get older as time goes by...).

```
public class Person {

    private int age;

    public Person(int age) { 
        this.age = age; 
    }

    public int GetAge() { 
        return age 
    }

    public void SetAge(int age) {
        if (this.age < age) { 
            this.age = age; 
        }
    }
}
```

**Abstraction** is used to extract and highlight the main functionality that will be shared for a generic *abstract class* or *interface*. Brief example is when we have an interface for an IAnimal. In this interface we just create a template for methods of Eat(int numOfBowls) and Sleep(double hours). **We have abstracted out the necessary methods for any animal** (this is abstraction). The code below will clearly show you what I mean, but I also gave an example of using **Inheritance** which is the other main concept of Objected-Oriented Programming (this will not be covered here since it's out of scope from the question at hand).

```
public interface IAnimal {
    void Eat(int numOfBowls);
    void Sleep(double hours);
}

public class Dog : IAnimal {

    public void Eat(int numOfBowls) {
        // eat numOfBowls passed in
    }

    public void Sleep(double hours) {
        // sleep for number of hours passed in
    }

    public void Bark() { 
        Console.WriteLine("woof");
    }
}
```