# What is abstraction in C#?

Tags: c#, class, oop, object, abstraction

I am confused in between many definitions of abstraction. 
can any one tell me what is abstraction and how can we achieve it ?

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21220155/what-does-abstraction-mean-in-programming

Comment: concentrate on concept rather then definition

Answer (score 0):

***Abstraction*** in **OOP theory** consists in *retaining only the relevant aspects of a real world object for a specific problem*. Thus we talk about **abstraction of the reality**. It's a *reduction*.

For example, in the real world we have cats and dogs that are vertebrate animals. Such an animal has properties such as head and legs, and operations like walking and eating. We will then define *classes* that will be Animal and Cat and Dog.

So we have the concept of **inheritence** where the cat and the dog inherits properties and operations that are common and that we will then put at the level of animal to not repeat these elements in the children class: that is the **generalization**. Also cats can meow and dogs can bark: that is the **specialization**.

Abstraction is thus a **projection of the real world into a more limited conceptual world**.

Doing abstraction is *identifying the properties and behaviors we need to design a computer system* and therefore software, and *we reject all that we don't need*.

For example, in a banking system, we identify customer that have a name, an address and so on. We take all things necessary and reject others like how they eat or how they walk or what is the last book they read.

Absraction is **defining the needed concepts** (the entities and their aspects and their behaviors and their relations) and **forgot what is not needed**. it's a *section of reality*.

We name **class** a **concept** that comes from the abstraction and **object** an **instance** of this concept within the software domain that will run on a computer that is thus a **materialization**.

All others OOP terms are vocabulary to define the means to do that.

For example **encapsulation** is the process to mask some properties and operations in the class that will become inaccessible from the exterior: these are only internal things and behaviours like a digestive system.

There is also **polymorphism** and *interfaces* in addition to *classes*.

[How to choose between private and protected access modifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58257849/how-to-choose-between-private-and-protected-access-modifier-to-encapsulate-membe/58258056#58258056)

[What is polymorphism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1031273/what-is-polymorphism-what-is-it-for-and-how-is-it-used/58197730#58197730)

[What is the difference between an interface and a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10914802/what-is-the-difference-between-an-interface-and-a-class-and-why-i-should-use-an/58174007#58174007)

Here are some Wiktionary definitions:

> The act of abstracting, separating, withdrawing, or taking away; withdrawal; the state of being taken away.
>
> The act of focusing on one characteristic of an object rather than the object as a whole group of characteristics; the act of separating said qualities from the object or ideas.
>
> The act of comparing commonality between distinct objects and organizing using those similarities; the act of generalizing characteristics; the product of said generalization.
>
> (computing) Any generalization technique that ignores or hides details to capture some kind of commonality between different instances for the purpose of controlling the intellectual complexity of engineered systems, particularly software systems.
>
> (computing) Any intellectual construct produced through the technique of abstraction.

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abstraction